# Sort by date with jmespath

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmespath

With a json output like :

```
{
   "Functions":[
      {
         "CodeSha256":"7NBvXXacp9x3aK3cKaI=",
         "FunctionName":"function_1",
         "FunctionArn":"arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:1111:function:function_1",
         "LastModified":"2015-02-09T11:35:31.084+0000"
      },
      {
         "CodeSha256":"7NBvXXacKaI=",
         "FunctionName":"function_3",
         "FunctionArn":"arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:1111:function:function_3",
         "LastModified":"2015-03-09T11:35:31.084+0000"
      },
      {
         "CodeSha256":"7NBvXXacaK3cKaI=",
         "FunctionName":"function_2",
         "FunctionArn":"arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:1111:function:function_2",
         "LastModified":"2015-02-11T11:35:31.084+0000"
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I return the two most recent Functions sorted by LastModified?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to use `reverse` and `sort_by` first. Then add `[:2]` for only two record :

```
aws lambda list-functions --query "reverse(sort_by(Functions, &LastModified))[:2]"
```

Comment: It doesn't work in all case because jmespath consider this: `"215-02-09T11:35:31.084+0000" > "2015-02-09T11:35:31.084+0000"`return `true` so you need to have date with the same amount of digit to apply the method above.

Comment: @bosskay972 Yep, coming to this late, but won't ISO dates all have the same number of characters, hence, for this question, the answer is correct? The crux of what you appear to be saying is that jmespath sorts by string or number only. It doesn't sort by date, as such but with ISO date format string sorting works pretty well.

Answer (score 9):

If you need top 1 last modified, whose name starts with 'abc'

```
--query "reverse(sort_by([?starts_with(name, 'abc')], &properties.lastModified))[:1]"
```