# How to get the most recently launched EC2 instance with AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm currently using the following CLI command to get the instance **PublicIPAddress** and **LaunchTime** for a given instance **Name** tag, 'myInstanceName':

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=myInstanceName' \ 
    --region us-east-1 \
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{PublicIpAddress: PublicIpAddress, LaunchTime: LaunchTime}'
```

This results in the following:

```
[
    {
        "LaunchTime": "2019-01-25T11:49:06.000Z",
        "PublicIpAddress": "11.111.111.11"
    }
]
```

This is fine, but if there are two instances with the same name I will get two results in my result JSON. I need to find a way to get the most recent instance for a given name.

**Solution Update**

This question is quite specific to EC2 instances. The issue can be resolved using two different methods, answered below:
[Parsing Result with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55286481/4125723)
[Using JMESPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55289610/4125723)

Please see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42414156/sort-by-date-with-jmespath) for more general sorting by date with JMESPath, and for further reading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort by date with jmespath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42414156/sort-by-date-with-jmespath)

Comment: If possible, Could you take a look on this post which I have tried earlier to get the list of latest instance creation in last X days in powershell ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77497402/to-get-the-instance-count-of-a-certain-period-via-launchtime-wrt-powershell

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using the [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) utility. It's a command-line JSON parser. If you're not familiar with it then I'd recommend the [jq playground](https://jqplay.org/) for experimentation.

First flatten the awcli results, as follows:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances  \
    --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{ip: PublicIpAddress, tm: LaunchTime}' \
    --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values= myInstanceName'
```

Note that I've aliased `LaunchTime` to `tm` for brevity. That will result in (unsorted) output like this:

```
[
  {
    "ip": "54.4.5.6",
    "tm": "2019-01-04T19:54:11.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ip": "52.1.2.3",
    "tm": "2019-03-04T20:04:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

Next, pipe this result into `jq` and sort by descending `tm` (the alias for `LaunchTime`), as follows:

```
jq 'sort_by(.tm) | reverse'
```

That will result in output like this:

```
[
  {
    "ip": "52.1.2.3",
    "tm": "2019-03-04T20:04:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ip": "54.4.5.6",
    "tm": "2019-01-04T19:54:11.000Z"
  }
]
```

Finally, use `jq` to filter out all but the first result, as follows:

```
jq 'sort_by(.tm) | reverse | .[0]'
```

This will yield one result, the most recently launched instance:

```
{
  "ip": "52.1.2.3",
  "tm": "2019-03-04T20:04:00.000Z"
}
```

Putting it all together, the final command is:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances  \
    --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{ip: PublicIpAddress, tm: LaunchTime}' \
    --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values= myInstanceName' | \
    jq 'sort_by(.tm) | reverse | .[0]'
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very useful, I was not aware of the sort_by function.
Great answer, I appreciate it!

Comment: @jarmod Could you take a look on this post which I have tried earlier to get the list of latest instance creation in last X days in powershell ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77497402/to-get-the-instance-count-of-a-certain-period-via-launchtime-wrt-powershell

Answer (score 14):

Here's a method for finding the latest-launched instance, and displaying data about it:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances  --query 'sort_by(Reservations[].Instances[], &LaunchTime)[:-1].[InstanceId,PublicIpAddress,LaunchTime]'
```

`sort_by(Reservations[].Instances[], &LaunchTime)[:-1]` will return the last instance launched. The fields are then retrieved from those instances.

To understand this type of fun, see:

- [JMESPath Tutorial — JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)
- [JMESPath Examples — JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/examples.html)

Comment: if possible, Could you take a look on this post which I have tried earlier to get the list of latest instance creation in last X days in powershell ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77497402/to-get-the-instance-count-of-a-certain-period-via-launchtime-wrt-powershell