# Get list of EC2 instances created since a date

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I want to retrieve a list of EC2 instances which were created in last x days. Here 'created' means the *first launch* of an instance. Is there a way to do this using AWS CLI or AWS Golang SDK?

I tried looking into Cloudtrail. Apparently, one could filter events within a specified period of time. So if I wanted to do the same for S3 Buckets, I would look for `CreateBucket` event in last x days. But unfortunately, I could not find a similar EventName for EC2 instances. The `RunInstances` event is not specific to the first launch of EC2 instances.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55284594/how-to-get-the-most-recently-launched-ec2-instance-with-aws-cli

Comment: `RunInstances` _is_ specific to the first launch of instances. Please note that one `RunInstances` command can be used to launch multiple Amazon EC2 instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the raw AWS CLI this is not possible without further post-processing of the unfiltered results. Please see below for the previous question/answer.

[How to get the most recently launched EC2 instance with AWS CLI? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55284594/how-to-get-the-most-recently-launched-ec2-instance-with-aws-cli)