# AWS instance created in last 48 hrs or last T hrs via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am following this link [How to get the most recently launched EC2 instance with AWS CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55284594/how-to-get-the-most-recently-launched-ec2-instance-with-aws-cli) but not getting appropriate results what I am expecting from

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=myInstanceName' \ 
    --region us-east-1 \
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{PublicIpAddress: PublicIpAddress, LaunchTime: LaunchTime}'
```

Is there anyway so that I can fetch out list of instances which was created in last 48 hrs or last T hrs via AWS CLI ??

Any hints or ideas on this ?

Comment: This information will be available in CloudTrail.