# sort the tables based on creation date or bucket name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

There is a sort icon next to each column. But it does not sort the table list.

[image]

Is there some other way to sort the tables?

Comment: Its a bug, you can report it to aws.

Comment: You could use the AWS CLI to list the tables and [do some fancy stuff with JMESPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42440103/174777) to sort the result.